# Binding a jQuery class change to a div ID hitting top of viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a complete novice trying to get my head around a clean, jQuery solution for binding a li class change to a SECTION id hitting the top of the viewport.  I realize this isn't a revolutionary concept (it's used regularly) but I searched first, and most of the solutions I'm seeing bind the class change to number of pixels scrolled.  I apologize if I just did a crappy job searching.

I don't believe it matters, but I've got a fixed position link bar that's visibility is tied to scrolling below 200px.

An abridged version of how I have it setup now:

**HTML:**

```
 <ul id="main-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Third</a></li>
 </ul>

<section id="1">
</section> 

<section id="2">
</section>

<section id="3">
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-links {
   display:none;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:90%;
   margin-left:7.5%;    
   }    

.main-links li{
        float:left;
        padding:0 .10em 2em .10em; 
        font-size:.75em; 
        font-weight:700;            
        }

.active {
   border-bottom:3px #000 solid;
   }
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $(".main-links").fadeIn();

} else {
    $(".main-links").fadeOut();

    }
});
```

Obviously what I'm looking to do is remove ".current" from section 1 and add it to section 2 once section2 hits the top of the viewport.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Here's a slightly changed jsfiddle, though I haven't done any work on the binding the class change...

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4SDesignStudio/6zvngxL3/)

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you want

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop(),
        idx = $('section').sort(function (a, b) {
                return top - $(b).offset().top;
              }).first().index('section'),
        el  = $('#main-links li').eq(idx);

    if (!el.hasClass('active')) {
        $('#main-links li').removeClass('active');
        el.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

It gets the scrolled distance from the top, then sorts the `section` elements based on their position from the top relative to the scrolled position, so the first element in the collection is the one closest to the top / being visible etc.
Then it gets the index of that element, and uses that index to get the menu item with the same index, and sets the class to that menu item and at the same time removes the class from the other menu items.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLo6sntm/3/)

Comment: The fiddle appears to do exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll work to implement into my design.  Thank you.  Not to take advantage of your time, but any chance you'd be willing to give me a quick breakdown of why this works?  Not your responsibility, but I'm trying to learn this stuff as opposed to just copy and pasting other peoples code.

Comment: @sforcash - added an explanation !

Comment: This absolutely worked in Chrome and Firefox.  I'm having an issue with it not working in IE though.  Any ideas?